How can I change the color of the explorer items in my vscode theme without changing the color of other sidebar elements?
The property sidebar.foreground changes the color of the explorer items which is what I want.
What I don't want is also to update the color of all the other elements in the sidebar (EG: search or SCM). Is this possible?

I don't think there is any way to change the explorer text colors without an extension, but any extension that does that would also change the colors of those file names in the editor tabs.  If you are still interested, let me know - I wrote such an extension.
